# How do I stop web pages/scripts from intercepting some (or all) of my keystrokes or hotkeys (e.g. Ctrl+Z)?

Tags: firefox, browser, javascript, hotkeys

Many websites (including this one) seem to think it's acceptable to assign their own custom functionality to system hotkey combinations.

For example, this text box I'm typing in right now has custom "undo" functionality which overrides the system default `Ctrl+Z` with its own (crappy) implementation.

How do I prevent JavaScript from intercepting some or all of my keys so I can regain control of my browser?

Comment: @harrymc This question isn't a duplicate. The other question you linked to is talking about shortcut keys as defined from a Firefox extension not working when Firefox developer tools is open. My question is about keys which are being intercepted by JavaScript on any web page. The two questions are not related.

Comment: @DavidPostill As above

Comment: I’m not sure whether the question is a duplicate, but it sure sounds like the two questions are related, and sometimes similar questions have the same answer. You might get more sympathy/support if you try the answers to the other question and report what happens.

Comment: @kreemoweet That looks better. Thank you.